# Understanding Image Resolution in Intermediate Layers of DINO Model (ViT)

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, transformer-model

I've been experimenting with the [DINO](https://github.com/facebookresearch/dino) model from Facebook Research and am trying to understand some specifics about its architecture. I'm aware that the input images are resized to a dimension of 224x224 before being processed by the model.

My main question revolves around the resolution of these images when they reach the intermediate layers, particularly layer 9. Does anyone know the resolution of the images at this layer or any other layers within the model?

Any insights or references would be greatly helpful. Thank you in advance!